# PHP Put a Date Stamp and a Time Stamp together

Tags: php, datetime

I got two different timestamps in milliseconds. One is for the chosen DATE. One for the chosen time. I need now to send this to an API and I have to put the DATE and the TIME together. How can I achieve this?

```
            $time = $request -> newTime1; //newTime1 is 1452800524000 which is: Thu Jan 14 2016 20:42:04 GMT+0100 (CET)
            $datum  = $request -> newDate1; //newDate1 is 1453676400000 which is: Mon Jan 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)

            $dateformatted = strtotime($datum);
            $timeformatted = date ("H:i:s",strtotime($time));

            $combinedDT =  strtotime("$dateformatted $timeformatted");

            $event_start = $combinedDT;
            $event_end = $event_start + 3600;

            //I want 25.1.2016 20:42
```

Comment: Please explain what result you want from the combination of a date `2016-01-25` and time of `2016-01-14T20:42:04`

Comment: I want the date (DayMonthYear) from newDate1 and the The time from the NewTime1. I probably need the Hours and Minutes from newTime1 just in milliseconds. I have to find out how many miliseconds 20:42:04 are and then add this to newDate1? Could this work? How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('CET');
$time = 'Thu Jan 14 2016 20:42:04 GMT+0100 (CET)';
$datum = 'Mon Jan 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)';
$t = strtotime($time);
$d = strtotime($datum);
$combined = strftime('%d.', $d) . intval(strftime('%m', $d)) . strftime('.%Y', $d)
    . strftime(' %H:%M', $t);
echo $combined;
```

output

```
25.1.2016 20:42
```

Comment: i tried it. Time is working fine but the date not. I get: 1452800524145367640025.1.2016 20:42

Comment: that's weird. when I ran my code, it printed the output you wanted. what change did u make?

Comment: u are right it. It is working now! But unfortunately the api is not eating the date. i need it in datetime (Format yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss) which i think it is now...

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that the time input is multiplied by 100 (not in seconds).
After you solve it the most simple way is too use two date functions

```
$time = 14528005240;
$datum  = 1453676400;
echo $date = date('d.m.Y',$datum).' '.date('H:i',$time);
```